# How can I make printf print unicode characters saved in a variable?

Tags: linux, printing, unicode, tcsh

I have this code to print a horizontal line using unicode character `\u2501`:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set horz_line = "'"
foreach x (`seq 1 1 80`)
   set horz_line = "${horz_line}\\u2501"
end
set horz_line = "${horz_line}\\n'"
printf $horz_line
```

But it is not giving what I expected. I expect the output to look like the one generated by below:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
foreach x (`seq 1 1 79`)
   printf '\u2501'
end
printf '\u2501\n'
```

The reason why I want to try out the code in the first block is because the code in second block works but is slow. When I run the second block code, I can see the whole line being drawn couple of characters at a time.

My thinking was that that's probably because `printf` is called 80 times. So I am trying out the first block approach where I generate a string of `\u2501\u2501.. (80 times)` and call `printf` just one to print that.

Answer (score 1):

The following gets what I want in the first code block in the question. It is significantly faster than the second code block.

```
#!/bin/tcsh
set horz_line = ""
foreach x (`seq 1 1 80`)
    set horz_line = ${horz_line}'\\u2550' # double line
end
printf "`echo $horz_line`\n"
unset horz_line
```

Comment: Good find! For me it had to be one backslash: `check="\u2718"` then later ``printf "`echo -e $check`"``